# Appending Objects Including Keyframes?

Tags: animation

Can you append an object, specifically 3 cameras together with their keyframes?
I have an old blend file that already has the camera movements that I want to replicate in a new blend file.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Sure, just append the Cameras to the new file (Shift F1). They will bring their associated actions with them by default. If the keyframes aren't ported for some reason, just append the specific actions of the cameras and link them.

Comment: thanks @Leander 

I was wondering because I tried it yesterday using 2.8 beta but it never worked. maybe with the new build?